# ionic3 highchart shows error during build

Tags: highcharts, ionic3, gauge

I am trying to populate Gauge in my ionic3 aps. Everything running well during ionic serve. But when i want to build the apps it just showing error and stop building the apps. the example that i followed : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/

the error during ionic cordova build android :

```
Argument of type '{ chart: { type: string; plotBackgroundColor: null; plotBackgroundImage: null; plotBorderWidth: n...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'. Types of property 'series' are incompatible. Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; tooltip: { valueSuffix: string; }; }[]' is not assignable to type '(SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions |...'. Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; tooltip: { valueSuffix: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions | ...'.
```

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

my .ts and html file is as follows:

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as c3 from "c3";
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
HighchartsMore(HighCharts);

ionViewDidLoad() {
     /* for sppedometer.....*/
  HighCharts.chart('meter_container', {
     chart: {
          type: 'gauge',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBackgroundImage: null,
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          plotShadow: false
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Oil Level'
      },
      pane: {
          startAngle: -150,
          endAngle: 150,
          background: [{
              backgroundColor: {
                  linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                  stops: [
                      [0, '#FFF'],
                      [1, '#333']
                  ]
              },
              borderWidth: 0,
              outerRadius: '109%'
          }, {
              backgroundColor: {
                  linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                  stops: [
                      [0, '#333'],
                      [1, '#FFF']
                  ]
              },
              borderWidth: 1,
              outerRadius: '107%'
          }, {
              // default background
          }, {
              backgroundColor: '#DDD',
              borderWidth: 0,
              outerRadius: '105%',
              innerRadius: '103%'
          }]
      },

      // the value axis
      yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,

          minorTickInterval: 'auto',
          minorTickWidth: 1,
          minorTickLength: 10,
          minorTickPosition: 'inside',
          minorTickColor: '#666',

          tickPixelInterval: 30,
          tickWidth: 2,
          tickPosition: 'inside',
          tickLength: 10,
          tickColor: '#666',
          labels: {
              step: 2,
              rotation: 'auto'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'km/h'
          },
          plotBands: [{
              from: 0,
              to: 70,
              color: '#55BF3B' // green
          }, {
              from: 70,
              to: 90,
              color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
          }, {
              from: 90,
              to: 100,
              color: '#DF5353' // red
          }]
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Speed',
          data: [80],
          tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' km/h'
          }
      }],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
  });
  /*==================*/
    
 }
```

```html
<ion-content >
 <div id="meter_container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have imported HighchartsMore incorrectly. It should be imported like that:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

Have you considered using `highcharts-angular` official Highcharts wrapper for Angular? It can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/jnrx6y8wj9